# Return a SQL Query into a shell script from oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, bash, unix, oracle11g

I'm writing a script that allows a user to select an option from a menu (which is done), and return from database which is stored in oracle11g.

```
pause(){
  read -p "Press [Enter Key To Continue]"
}

connect(){
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
sqlplus64 '******@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=oracle.***********)(Port=****))(CONNECT_DATA=(*******)))'
}


show_menu() {
  clear
  echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
  echo " M A I N - M E N U"
  echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
  echo "1. Connect to Database"
  echo "2. Query Table"
  echo "3. Exit"
  echo "_____________________"

}

one() {
  connect
  pause
}
```

I'm using astericks in the code snippet to save some of the personal information. My question is, how would I go about, for example, having the user select 2, and making the database return, for example

```
SELECT * FROM *
```

Directly back to command line? Is this far more difficult than I think? The connect() function allows me to log into the database server, but I need to manually enter my password and then I'm logged into oracle until I close the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute it as below in shell

```
OUTPUT=/path/to/sqlplus64 user/password\@sid << EOF
select * from table;
EOF

echo $OUTPUT;
```

You can replace the query with what you get from user.